# Stop Django from inserting or updating SQL Server computed column

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class LocationMaster(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    open_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    months_open = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True) # Calculated column in SQL Server
    maturity = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) # Calculated column in SQL Server

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        # ?? Something here
        super(LocationMaster, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_field)
```

Two of my columns are SQL Server computed columns. I would like to display these columns in my application, including in the admin, but not insert or update these columns since they are computed. Without modified my model, I get this error:

```
('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The column "months_open" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator. (271) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

How do I modify my model so that Django does not attempt to insert or update these specific columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went with this work around in the save method to ignore the computed SQL Server columns. Found here: [Prevent Django from updating identity column in MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158559/prevent-django-from-updating-identity-column-in-mssql)

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    # Hack to not save the maturity and months_open as they are computed columns
    self._meta.local_fields = [f for f in self._meta.local_fields if f.name not in ('maturity', 'months_open')]
    super(LocationMaster, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue when a field is updated with PostgreSQL triggers, but django overwrites it's value (in same transaction).

This is a generic class decorator that prevents sending `enabled=False` fields to database (perhaps in any query, like `UPDATE`).

```
def prevent_updating_non_editable_fields(clazz):
      """ prevents sending non`editable` fields in queries  """
      meta = clazz._meta
      meta.local_concrete_fields = [f for f in meta.local_concrete_fields if f.editable]
      return clazz


@prevent_updating_editable_fields
class MyModel(models.Model):
       precomputed = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
```

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding `editable=False` to the field.

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that does not appear to work. I have added "editable=False" to both fields, but still received the same error.

Comment: When attempting to add or update a record via the admin interface.